# What does it mean if a resonant particle has a zero decay width in 3-body decay?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, resonance

I'm working on a problem that assumes a zero decay width for the resonance in a three-body decay with resonance, $A \rightarrow B + C (\rightarrow 1 + 2)$, and $\Gamma_{C\rightarrow 1+2} = 0$. I should find the phase space for the process, but I cannot really grasp what does it mean by that the width is zero. Infinite lifetime? Isn't this then just a 2-body decay?

Thank you for your answers.